# display json object in dropdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, dropdown

I am hoping to get some help from the community. I am trying to understand how to write a code to read from a json file to a dropdown . I am using node.js to run the app.

I am accessing json object from  "http://localhost:4300/location": 
{
  "1": "82 North Wall Quay, Dublin 1",
  "2": "Eastwall Wall Road, Dublin 3",
  "3": "4 Grand Canal Square,Dublin 2 "
}

```
<select id="location"> </select>

function populateSelect(shop_location){

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status==200) {

showResult(xhttp.responseText);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:4300/location", true);
xhttp.send();
}

function showResult(jsonData) {
var txt = "";
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
jsonData.forEach (x=>{txt = txt + "<br>" +x["Title"];})

document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the data you are working with. E.g. the `.forEach()` method only works with arrays...

Comment: Is your jsonData a json array or a json object? Show the contents of jsonData.

Comment: {
  "1": "82 North Wall Quay, Dublin 1",
  "2": "Eastwall Wall Road, Dublin 3",
  "3": "4 Grand Canal Square,Dublin 2 "
}

Comment: Please include all the relevant information in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for..in` loop to iterate through all the `keys` of the JSON object and create a new `option` element for each of them.

Finally use the `append()` method to add each newly created `option` element to the `select` element.

Check below:

```js
var jsonData = { 
  "1": "82 North Wall Quay, Dublin 1",
  "2": "Eastwall Wall Road, Dublin 3",
  "3": "4 Grand Canal Square,Dublin 2"
};

function showResult(jsonData) {
  let loc = document.getElementById("location");
  
  for(let key in jsonData) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = jsonData[key];
    option.value = key;
    loc.append(option);
  }
}

showResult(jsonData);
```

```html
<select id="location">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan ! This works well in the code snippet but I get an error on node js ReferenceError: document is not defined for let loc = document.getElementById("location"); hmm i might need to do some parse as  node.js doesn't have DOM like the browser does built-in

Comment: this works fine if I define the variable but I would like to get json from an api - this is as far as i got https://codepen.io/acazacu07/pen/YzyXgdN

Comment: @anca glad it worked for you and that you managed to find a solution for your api call. It wasn't obvious from your question that you had the api problem as well. I'll give you an upvote to support you since you are a new member. In the future, try to include all possible relevant information in your question so you can get more accurate help. Have a good one! :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var locationRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

locationRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4300/location')
locationRequest.onload = function() {
  var locationData = JSON.parse(locationRequest.responseText);
  showResult(locationData);
  console.log(locationData);
}

locationRequest.send();


function showResult(locationRequest) {
  let loc = document.getElementById("location");

  for (let key in locationRequest) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = locationRequest[key];
    option.value = key;
    loc.append(option);
  }
}
```